# batch file to detect exist of file (determine which OS and uninstall program accordingly)

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

I am trying to figure out what's wrong with my batch file to determine if a folder exists and then running the correct uninstall for a client on that machine.

if the machine is x64 the client is in one folder and in another if x86. i cannot base this on the cpu architecture or on winver because I have windows 7 32-bit and 64-bit in addition to 32-bit and 64-bit xp in my environment.

I've tried the following:

```
if exist C:\Windows\ccmsetup GOTO W64
else
C:\windows\system32\ccmsetup\ccmsetup.exe /uninstall
W64
C:\windows\ccmsetup\ccmsetup.exe /uninstall
```

or

```
IF EXIST C:\Windows\ccmsetup GOTO W64
W64
C:\windows\ccmsetup\ccmsetup.exe /uninstall
GOTO NEXT
IF EXIST C:\Windows\ system32\ccmsetup GOTO W32
W32
C:\windows\system32\ccmsetup\ccmsetup.exe /uninstall
```

or

```
IF EXIST C:\Windows\ccmsetup GOTO W64
IF NOT EXIST C:\Windows\ccmsetup GOTO W32
W32
C:\windows\system32\ccmsetup\ccmsetup.exe /uninstall
W64
C:\windows\ccmsetup\ccmsetup.exe /uninstall
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work in your case?

```
IF EXIST C:\Windows\ccmsetup\ccmsetup.exe GOTO W64
IF EXIST C:\windows\system32\ccmsetup\ccmsetup.exe GOTO W32
ECHO Nothing to uninstall
GOTO :EOF
:W32
C:\windows\system32\ccmsetup\ccmsetup.exe /uninstall
GOTO :EOF
:W64
C:\windows\ccmsetup\ccmsetup.exe /uninstall
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in the first and second lines of the script?